# Using Media Queries to resize text by screen size

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to resize navigation text based on the screen size using media queries. The size is being displayed as 30px, the smaller screen size, but when the screen is large it is still 30px. Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
 <a class="logo" style="cursor: pointer">LIT</a>
 <div class="sidebar" id="active">
 <a style="cursor: pointer;" id="projectLink">samples &nbsp;</a>
 <a style="cursor: pointer;" id="aboutLink">services &nbsp;</a>
 <a style="cursor: pointer;" id="blogLink">tweets &nbsp;</a>
 <a style="cursor: pointer;" id="contactLink" class="mail" onclick="openForm()">contact</a>
 </div>
```

SCSS:

```
   .sidebar{
    z-index: 1;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: black;

    /* If the screen size is 601px wide or more, set the font-size of <div> to 80px */
    @media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
      .sidebar {
        font-size: 80px;
      }
    }

    /* If the screen size is 600px wide or less, set the font-size of <div> to 30px */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .sidebar {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are wrapping your `.sidebar` inside another `.sidebar`**

Bring them out will help:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .sidebar{
        z-index: 1;
        font-weight: bolder;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 0px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        color: black;
      }
      /* If the screen size is 601px wide or more, set the font-size of <div> to 80px */
      @media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
        .sidebar {
          font-size: 80px;
        }
      }
      /* If the screen size is 600px wide or less, set the font-size of <div> to 30px */
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .sidebar {
          font-size: 30px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="sidebar">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```